# Getting previous site Title in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-online

Using `document.referrer` I am able to get the previous site URL but I want to get the previous site title also. How to do this?

Comment: How are you getting redirected to the current site from the previous one? is it through a button/link click or something else? Also are you in position to add query string to the url?

Comment: By clicking on link I am going to next site, so there I need to have previous site title

Comment: On that link button, can you modify URL by adding a query string? I mean the href of link button is set by you in code?

Comment: If you want to escape server calls to get title, then you can append `_spPageContextInfo.webTitle` as a query string parameter. And on Next Site you can retrieve using `JSRequest.QueryString["YourQueryString"]`.

Comment: If using QueryString, beware of XSS, e.g., ?prevTitle=<script>alert("Peekaboo!")</script>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use JSOM for this.

```
function retrieveWebSite() {
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(document.referrer);
    var oWebsite = clientContext.get_web();

    clientContext.load(this.oWebsite);

    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
}

function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {
    alert('Title: ' + oWebsite.get_title());
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to escape server calls to get Web Title, and are in position to set the URL of the Links which takes users to `Next Site`.

Then make use of an OOB object `_spPageContextInfo` which holds lots of important and much needed values, and Web Title is one of them. `_spPageContextInfo.webTitle` is the one we are interested in.

**On Previous Site**

The links on which when you click takes you to the `Next Site`, you can add query string into the HREF. Something like below

```
var webTitle = _spPageContextInfo.webTitle;
var urlToNextSite = 'http://YourNextSite.com?PreviousWebTitle=webTitle';
```

**On Next Site**

Using `JSRequest` we can retrieve the query string values.

```
JSRequest.EnsureSetup();
var q = JSRequest.QueryString["PreviousWebTitle"];
```

> **Note**: While using Query Strings, we need to be aware of `XSS attacks`